# How to handle errors in parsing the curl response using jq

Tags: bash, shell, curl, jq

```
   local response=response.json
    local status=$(curl -s -w %{http_code} "http://www.google.com" -o $response)

    local name=$(cat $response | jq -r .name)
    local address=$(cat $response | jq -r .address)
    if [ $status  = 200 ] && [ $name = "John" ]; then
       # Process response
    else
       # Error
    fi
```

I am processing more requests using the above approach. All the requests fails with the above scenario

If there is a invalid URL, response.json is not available. I am getting error as below 2 times as I have parsed the $response 2 times

```
response.json not found, No such file or directory
response.json not found, No such file or directory
```

How can I handle these type of errors in a better way using the curl and jq?

Comment: Why not just test whether response.json is created?  (I'd first mv response.json if it exists so that one can more easily check whether it was created.)

Comment: How and where do i check it?

Comment: Please read up on bash, and in particular `if` and `test`.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
if [ $status  = 200 ]; then
  if [ -f $response ]; then
    local name=$(cat $response | jq -r .name)
    if [ $name = "John" ]; then
      local address=$(cat $response | jq -r .address)
      # Process response
    else
      # Error name is not John
    fi
  else
    # Error no response file
  fi
else
   # Error status not 200
fi
```

You can add more condition - key "name" is present, "address" is present, ... If you dont't want to handle errors, just remove the else section

Comment: Is there a better way instead of multiple if statements.

Comment: If you want to handle such decision tree logic, I'm afraid there is no better way. Another approach is to redirect stderr to `/dev/null` :-)